# Pythonic equivalent of this function?

Tags: python

I have a function to port from another language, could you please help me make it "pythonic"?

Here the function ported in a "non-pythonic" way (this is a bit of an artificial example - every task is associated with a project or "None", we need a list of distinct projects, distinct meaning no duplication of the .identifier property, starting from a list of tasks):

```
@staticmethod
def get_projects_of_tasks(task_list):

    projects = []
    project_identifiers_seen = {}

    for task in task_list:

        project = task.project

        if project is None:
            continue

        project_identifier = project.identifier

        if project_identifiers_seen.has_key(project_identifier):
            continue

        project_identifiers_seen[project_identifier] = True
        projects.append(project)

    return projects
```

I have specifically not even started to make it "pythonic" not to start off on the wrong foot (e.g. list comprehension with "if project.identifier is not None, filter() based on predicate that looks up the dictionary-based registry of identifiers, using set() to strip duplicates, etc.)

EDIT:

Based on the feedback, I have this:

```
@staticmethod
def get_projects_of_tasks(task_list):

    projects = []
    project_identifiers_seen = set()

    for task in task_list:

        project = task.project

        if project is None:
            continue

        project_identifier = project.identifier

        if project_identifier in project_identifiers_seen:
            continue

        project_identifiers_seen.add(project_identifier)
        projects.append(project)

    return projects
```

Comment: You can combine the two continue tests, which will make this easier to read.

Comment: How do you recommend I do that?

Comment: `if project is None or project.identifier in project_identifiers_seen: continue`

Comment: I dont't like that so much because it would mean accessing project.identifier again later on in the code. .identifier is a property access, it is based on a formula and should not be cached inside the object as you would a "singleton" instance or an expensive "lazy load".

Comment: That's a good reason to not do that, but it's also a previously unexpressed requirement.

Comment: You might like to look at the promise shown in my answer to cache accesses to `project.identifier`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's nothing massively unPythonic about this code. A couple of possible improvements:

- `project_identifiers_seen` could be a set, rather than a dictionary.
- `foo.has_key(bar)` is better spelled `bar in foo`
- I'm suspicious that this is a `staticmethod` of a class. Usually there's no need for a class in Python unless you're actually doing data encapsulation. If this is just a normal function, make it a module-level one.

Comment: Right, makes a lot of sense. I'll replace has_key() with just "in" and I will use a set instead. No control over the @staticmethod decorator, unfortunately. Anything else for efficiency and compactness?

Answer (score 3):

```
def get_projects_of_tasks(task_list):
    seen = set()
    return [seen.add(task.project.identifier) or task.project #add is always None
            for task in task_list if 
            task.project is not None and task.project.identifier not in seen]
```

This works because (a) `add` returns `None` (and `or` returns the value of the last expression evaluated) and (b) the mapping clause (the first clause) is only executed if the if clause is `True`.

There is no reason that it has to be in a list comprehension - you could just as well set it out as a loop, and indeed you may prefer to. This way has the advantage that it is clear that you are just building a list, and what is supposed to be in it.

I've not used `staticmethod` because there is rarely a need for it. Either have this as a module-level function, or a `classmethod`.

---

An alternative is a generator (thanks to @delnan for point this out):

```
def get_projects_of_tasks(task_list):
    seen = set()
    for task in task_list:
        if task.project is not None and task.project.identifier not in seen:
           identifier = task.project.identifier
           seen.add(identifier)
           yield task.project
```

This eliminates the need for a side-effect in comprehension (which is controversial), but keeps clear what is being collected.

For the sake of avoiding another if/continue construction, I have left in two accesses to `task.project.identifier`. This could be conveniently eliminated with the use of a promise library.

---

This version uses promises to avoid repeated access to task.project.identifier without the need to include an if/continue:

```
from peak.util.proxies import LazyProxy, get_cache # pip install ProxyTypes

def get_projects_of_tasks(task_list):
    seen = set()
    for task in task_list:
        identifier = LazyProxy(lambda:task.project.identifier) # a transparent promise
        if task.project is not None and identifier not in seen:
           seen.add(identifier)
           yield task.project
```

This is safe from AttributeErrors because `task.project.identifier` is never accessed before `task.project` is checked.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I don't think this is obfuscated; in fact, I find concise code far more readable.

Comment: While this might work, I wouldn't consider if "Pythonic" -- the point of "being pythonic" is to make the code more readible, not pack the code so densely that it can't be understood.

Comment: @mgilson I rather think that dense code is more readable than unnecessarily inflated code, especially when using idioms like list comprehensions.

Comment: A 154-character line is problematic IMO. If this were broken into a multi-line list comprehension, I would find it quite readable. But even then, I wouldn't consider mutating an object inside a list comprehension "pythonic" -- acceptable, perhaps, but not entirely in keeping with the list comprehension idiom.

Comment: there is a line between being *concise* and *encoded*, regex expressions when too long or complicated go from concise to **encoded** very quickly, list comprehension abuse crosses that line just as quickly.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson So, which part of this did you find confusing? Or are you just complaining about nothing?

Comment: For starters, one of the operands of the `or` exists merely for side effect and always evaluates to `None`. This is almost, but not quite entirely unlike every Python idiom I'm aware of. Also, this "one-liner" is more complex than `for task in task_list: { if task... in seen: continue; seen.add(task...);  yield task }` (or something similar) in most measures of complexity aside from SLoC.

Comment: Wow... this is "clever" but a bit cryptic. Had to scratch my head before I got what it's doing.

Comment: @Marcin you used the word *confusing*, I used the word **obfuscated**, I didn't even get to the **obfuscated side effects** that others have mentioned as well, the questions about **most pythonic** this is **not**. Pythonic means **idiomatic python**, the concensus is this isn't idiomatic Python.

Comment: @Robottinosino If so, then write it out as an explicit loop.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Almost every unique-list-type question on SO has five answers along these lines. It's clearly a well-known technique, and you can't even say why you find this confusing; you just keep repeating the word "obfuscated". Well done, you know that word.

Comment: @Marcin Yeah, and every "how do I define dynamic variables" question has five answers using `eval`/`exec` (often trying to use the former to execute statements, which speaks volumes of the poster's Python expertise). That doesn't mean it's a Python idiom - the Python idiom is "just use a darn collection (likely, a dict)". It just means a couple of people who are confident to post answers think it's a good idea.

Comment: @delnan Right, but the difference there is that you have a substantive criticism of the technique. Here all you have is the claim that an entirely equivalent form involving basically the exact same text in a slightly different format is simpler.

Comment: @Marcin: As I said, apply any common complexity metric to the two solutions. For instance, the line is longer and expressions are nested more deeply. Another issue is that operators are used in a rather unusual way (make left operand perform its side effect rather than its logical value, then throw it away). Yet another thing: List comprehensions for side effects (i.e. `[print("foo") for _ in range(10)]`) are generally considered un-idiomatic, and I'm not sure your solution is far away from that.

Comment: @delnan List comprehensions for side-effects are un-idiomatic because they unnecessarily create a datastructure which is thrown away. It honestly just sounds like you don't like extended list comprehension syntax very much.

Comment: Look through some of the answers I've given, you'll find I use list comprehensions (and generator expressions - same difference) a lot. My code base also contains a few generator expressions and whatever-comprehensions that span two or three lines. It's not that I dislike long expressions; I dislike *complicated* expressions. And since *all five* people who bothered to comment consider your solution either hard to comprehend or non-idiomatic, it can't be just because we're all too dumb to read Python.

Comment: @delnan (a) You are the only person who has commented who answers a lot of python questions (b) You are the only one who has even attempted to justify their comments (c) all but one of your criticisms could apply to any list comprehension with an if-clause, so excuse me if I find it less than devastating.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11949/discussion-between-delnan-and-marcin)

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
project_list = {task.project.identifier:task.project for task in task_list if task.project is not None}
return project_list.values()
```

For 2.6- use dict constructor instead:

```
return dict((x.project.id, x.project) for x in task_list if x.project).values()
```

Comment: It is worth mentioning that this would mess up the order of the project list -- (which might not matter at all).

Comment: I didn't even know Python had dictionary comprehensions as well as list comprehensions!

Comment: @Robottinosino, in 2.7+ only.

Comment: @Robottinosino: you can use [dict constructor](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict) instead. In any case, your function is an one-liner.

Comment: @thg435: Interesting. Care to share the code for that, please?

Answer (score 1):

Some say [EAFP](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-eafp) is pythonic, so:

```
@staticmethod
def get_projects_of_tasks(task_list):

    projects = {}

    for task in task_list:
        try:
            if not task.project.identifier in projects:
                projects[task.project.identifier] = task.project
        except AttributeError:
            pass

    return projects.values()
```

of cours an explicit check wouldn't be wrong either, and would of course be better if many tasks have not project.

And just one dict to keep track of seen identifiers and projects would be enough, if the order of the projects matters, then a [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections#collections.OrderedDict) (python2.7+) could come in handy.

Comment: Many tasks have None as the associated project. All tasks still "unassigned" to a project, that is. This throws a lot of exceptions... doesn't that have performance implications?

Comment: @Robottinosino, I would say so -- better to check explicitly in that case. `try` is cheap, but `except` is expensive.

Comment: Yes, if the case of `task.project` being `None` is common, then it would be better to check explicitly (altough exceptions in python arn't as expensive as they are in java for example). I thaught it would be the exceptinoal case... Nevertheless, I'll leave my answer like this for the 'pythonic' aspect.

Answer (score 1):

There are already a lot of good answers, and, indeed, you have accepted one! But I thought I would add one more option. A number of people have seen that your code could be made more compact with generator expressions or list comprehensions. I'm going to suggest a hybrid style that uses generator expressions to do the initial filtering, while maintaining your `for` loop in the final filter.

The advantage of this style over the style of your original code is that it simplifies the flow of control by eliminating `continue` statements. The advantage of this style over a single list comprehension is that it avoids multiple accesses to `task.project.identifier` in a natural way. It also handles mutable state (the `seen` set) transparently, which I think is important.

```
def get_projects_of_tasks(task_list):
    projects = (task.project for task in task_list)
    ids_projects = ((p.identifier, p) for p in projects if p is not None)

    seen = set()
    unique_projects = []
    for id, p in ids_projects:
        if id not in seen:
            seen.add(id)
            unique_projects.append(p)
    return unique_projects
```

Because these are generator expressions (enclosed in parenthesis instead of brackets), they don't build temporary lists. The first generator expression creates an iterable of projects; you could think of it as performing the `project = task.project` line from your original code on all the projects at once. The second generator expression creates an iterable of `(project_id, project)` tuples. The `if` clause at the end filters out the `None` values; `(p.identifier, p)` is only evaluated if `p` passes through the filter. Together, these two generator expressions do away with your first two `if` blocks. The remaining code is essentially the same as yours.

Note also the excellent suggestion from [Marcin/delnan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10820225/577088) that you create a generator using `yield`. This cuts down further on the verbosity of your code, boiling it down to its essentials:

```
def get_projects_of_tasks(task_list):
    projects = (task.project for task in task_list)
    ids_projects = ((p.identifier, p) for p in projects if p is not None)

    seen = set()
    for id, p in ids_projects:
        if id not in seen:
            seen.add(id)
            yield p
```

The only disadvantage -- in case this isn't obvious -- is that if you want to permanently store the projects, you have to pass the resulting iterable to `list`.

```
projects_of_tasks = list(get_projects_of_tasks(task_list))
```